# Excel Cell Lookup

Tags: excel, lookup

I need to return word after "-" for each cell.

software - agent

software - java

application - java

infrastructure - number

I want to be able to write a formula that will return:

agent

java

java

number

Is there a formula for it? There are more possibility of word to be return so it is not just "agent", "java", and "number".

Comment: @pnuts - no. There is always "-". I want Cell A1 = software - agent. Cell A2 = software - application. Cell A3 = Infrastructure - number. Return: B1 should be "agent". B2 = "application" B 3 = "number".

Answer (score 3):

In cell B1, enter the formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("-",A1))
```

and copy and paste cell B1 for the required number of rows in column B.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Text to Columns and use the (-) character as your Delimited character to separate the columns.